# Is there a way to link data by names in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I am using Google Forms and Sheets to create a way of tracking services including time for some of our students. I have the forms linked to a Sheet and am able to pull the "Clock In" data and "Clock Out" data into a single sheet. My issue is: when I go to analyze using pivot tables it pulls the data from the cell of the next row (students do not necessarily clock in/out in the order they arrive). Is there a way I can link the data by name and then order by time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Quick View of Issue]

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12pUuucD2MVh1Ei5rT_hWlsdQoDkmJQ_FlYNYY3pMd9E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am sorry I am a new user and I am waiting to get 10 rep before I can share an image! I am trying!

Comment: I was able to share a sample of my sheet. I appreciate any input! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can but not in one go because pivot tables are not so advanced. create a new sheet and paste this in **A1** cell and then crate your pivot table from this sheet:

```
={QUERY({Combination!A1:E}, "where Col1 is not null order by Col3, toDate(Col1) , toDate(Col2)", 1),
  QUERY({Combination!F1:I}, "where Col1 is not null order by Col3, toDate(Col1) desc, toDate(Col2) desc", 1)}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for a link! One more quick question on the QUERY, It seams it orders then by time out before date. IE now I have two posts for Testing 2 and because I clocked out today 4/29 at 8:28:44 it is ordering it before the 4/25/2019 13:14:51. Is there another parameter I can add to the QUERRY that says order by date then time? Again I appreciate your response!

Comment: **toDate** covers the whole timestamp (date + time including). I believe that scenario you describe can be solved if you remove one (or both) **desc** from query fx